# Computing error in $N$-Body simulations

Tags: error-analysis, many-body

I want to know how good my integrator is by computing $\log|E-E_{\text{start}}|$. This means I compute the kinetic energy at the beginning and during every time step. Does that make sense? Or has $E$ to be the sum of kinetic + potential energy? And what about $\log|\frac{E}{E_{\text{start}}}|$? Is that a good way to check the quality of the integrator?

Answer (score 1):

Comparing energy to the initial energy will only tell whether the algorithm preserves total energy or not. Even if it does preserve energy to great accuracy, this is not sufficient to conclude that the algorithm is good. The calculated approximate solution can be very far from the actual solution.

An algorithm for calculating solution of an initial value problem is good when its result is close to actual solution of the problem. This is often impossible to check directly since the actual solution is unavailable.

The algorithm should be constructed in such a way that the error made in each step, although unknown, is known to be smaller than some declared desired value. One can then set the value of the greatest acceptable error and run the program.

Comment: It's trivial to invent an algorithm which meets the OP's criteria exactly: the position and velocity of all bodies at the end of the time step = position and velocity at the beginning of the step. It's not a *good* algorithm - though it runs very fast and it's guaranteed to be stable for any size of time step ;)